# Adding a splash screen to LibGDX game whilst using Assets.load()

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to add a Splash Screen on my game while my game loads whilst still using the code

`Assets.load();`

to load my Assets. Very simple question, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

when you are using [AssetManager](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html) you should just show some animation/loading label while calling the **update** method so it should look like:

```
    AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.load("small.png", Texture.class);

    //in render method
    if( !manager.update() )
    {
        renderAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        startRegularGame();
    }
```

the update method returns true when all resources are loaded.

---

If you are using [Screen](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) class you can just create a special Screen with only manager updateing in render method. When resources will be loaded just set a game screen.